Distinct setvars in metamath
Metamath uses a very special system of variable distinctness to avoid having to codify capture-avoiding substitution in other formal systems. In metamath/set.mm for example, there is an axiom $$\vdash (\varphi \to \forall x \varphi)$$
provided that $x$ and $\varphi$ are distinct. Here, $x$ is a setvar, which is supposed to be a metavariable that ranges over actual variables in first order logic.
I might have confused myself over this matter, but if this is so, we should in principle have constants $\mathtt{v}_1$, $\mathtt{v}_2$ etc corresponding to the actual variables, with axioms like $\textrm{setvar}\,\mathtt{v}_1$. A metamath theorem $\vdash \forall x x = x$ should represent a family of theorems (which are strings of constant symbols) like $\vdash \forall \mathtt{v}_1 \mathtt{v}_1 = \mathtt{v}_1$. And in practice these concrete variables never appear because they are not needed. However, suppose this is true, what is there to stop me if, in the axiom above, I were to substitute $x$ with $\mathtt{v}_1$, and $\varphi$ with $\mathtt{v}_1 = \mathtt{v}_2$? The string $\mathtt{v}_1 = \mathtt{v}_2$ doesn't contain any metavariables, and so the distinctness check will never complain, which means I have now produced this theorem
$$\vdash (\mathtt{v}_1 = \mathtt{v}_2 \to \forall \mathtt{v}_1 \mathtt{v}_1 = \mathtt{v}_2)$$
which is nonsense.
Which part of my understanding is incorrect?

I think your problem is in the idea that you can add constants of type setvar.  I don’t know if doing so is inconsistent or just gives meaningless stuff like you derived.

I am confused about "... provided that $x$ and $\varphi$ are distinct". Don't you mean "... provided that $x$ does not occur in $\varphi$" or some such?

@AndrejBauer It means that whatever terms you substitute x and phi with have to have distinct variables (meaning those variables are registered as pairwise distinct).  It just happens to be that the only possible valid substitute for x is a variable (since it has type setvar and the only way to construct a setvar is via a variable), but that mechanism is used elsewhere in Metamath.

@AndrejBauer It just happens to be the word metamath chose, and it is stronger than being distinct (in the usual sense).

Ah, thanks. (I don't speak metamath, I am just impressed whenever Mario Carneiro gives a talk about it.)

@AndrejBauer Metamath is so simple that you could learn it and write your own checker in about 2-3 days.

Yes, that's what Mario says and it's impressive.

The meaning of the "distinct variables" is explained on the set.mm page. It mentions for a $(x, \varphi)$ disjoint condition:

where whatever setvar variable is substituted for  may not appear in the wff expression substituted for ,

So the disjoint/distinct rule does not care about constants, but only variables, and assuming $\mathrm{v}_1$, $\mathrm{v}_2$ are both constants, the substitution would be accepted.
In practice the setvar sort is only used for variables and never for constants, as the name implies. A constant is always declared as a class sort, and might be assumed or proven to be set, or as a wff sort.
I don't think it makes sense to try to interpret $\forall \mathrm{v}_1$ if $\mathrm{v}_1$ is a constant. A constant would have only one possible value, so one could drop the $\forall \mathrm{v}_1$ and obtain the tautological $$\vdash \mathrm{v}_1 = \mathrm{v}_2 \rightarrow \mathrm{v}_1 = \mathrm{v}_2$$
Original answer assuming $\mathrm{v}_1$ and $\mathrm{v}_2$ are setvar variables:
In your example, the wff expression substituted for $\varphi$ is $\mathrm{v}_1 = \mathrm{v}_2$, and the setvar variable substituted for $x$ is $\mathrm{v}_1$, which occurs in $\mathrm{v}_1 = \mathrm{v}_2$, so that substitution would not be accepted.
The choice of word "distinct" is maybe misleading here, that's why I'm usually rather calling them "disjoint variables" requirements.

If that is true, suppose we have two distinct wffs $\varphi, \psi$, are we not allowed to substitute them with $x = y$ and $z = w$ respectively? Notice that the constant $=$ is being repeated here.

The full text of the rule is the two expressions that are substituted for the two variables in a distinct variable pair must not have any variables in common, so the constant "equal sign" would not be checked.

I think @Trebors question is about constants and not variables.   (I think it would have been more clear if he didn’t use typical variable names.) That should be something that would be formalizable, but meaningless.  Would it lead to inconsistencies?  I’m not sure.

He is talking about explicitly adding constants of type setvar to the language.

Indeed I misunderstood the $\mathrm{v}$ for variables. In practice we have only class constants, no setvar constant, but if there were, the substitution would be legit, since only variables are checked.

I shall try to edit my answer!

After going to the specific section @ThierryArnoux linked to I found myself missing this paragraph:

In fact, the Metamath language cannot even express specific, actual theorems such as "$(\mathtt v_1 = \mathtt v_2 → \mathtt v_1 = \mathtt v_2)$." We would have to do that outside of the Metamath system. [...] Instead, the distinct variable condition on dtru is enforced at the level of theorem schemes.

So it seems that indeed this produces meaningless results. This shouldn't be inconsistent though, since there is no way in the system to leverage the existence of a $\textrm{setvar}$ constant to do anything — it is impossible to prove new theorems that don't contain these new constants, by a simple case analysis on the formal system (if I didn't miss any rule). So the resulting formal system would just be the same (meta)theorems adjoined with a bunch of garbage.
